# Items in flex container overlap

Tags: css, flexbox

When I try this code, the two dots overlap each other as well as the text.

Why? How can I get them to be side by side?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="dot" />
  <span class="dot" /> some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't close the spans properly

```css
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .dot {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: black;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <span class="dot"></span>      
      <span class="dot"></span>     
      some text
    </div>
```

Comment: Typo-error questions should be removed after comment, shouldn't they?